# vim Repeatable Motion that Distinguishes Vertical and Horizontal

Tags: vim, vim-plugins

I've been looking for a plugin like repmo that can repeat my previous horizontal movement and previous vertical movement separately, and reverse the direction of the motion. (e.g. `5j` could be repeated with `<C-j>` and `<C-l>` would give me `5l`).

[This plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4914) claims to do exactly what I want, but hasn't been updated for a while and fails to install with vundle (invalid arguments for function empty(maparg))

Is there any other plugin that has this functionality?

Comment: The last update is less than a year ago; it's still likely it's being maintained. Try a "normal" install into `~/.vim/plugin` without Vundle, and try to contact the author if that fails, too.

Comment: Unfortunately the normal install fails, and the plugin author's email address seems to no longer be in use.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem installing with NeoBundle from the Git repository. I have a hunch that it's got to do with the '-' in the first part of the path.

I successfully installed it with the line:

```
NeoBundle 'repeatable-motions.vim'
```

This successfully pulls the .zip from [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4914) and installs plugin and help without error.

I use:

```
map <leader>a <Plug>RepeatMostRecentMotion
```

As generally I just want to repeat the last motion in the same direction.